# Exception with owned collections with EF Core and CosmosDB provider

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Entity Framework Core context with CosmosDB provider and only one entity:

```
public class Entity1
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

here are the inner objects of the entity:

```
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public List<SubItem> SubItems { get; set; }
}

public class SubItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The class `Entity1` have an `owned` property of type collection of `Item` and this have another `owned` property of type collection `SubItem`. This is the configuration file for `Entity1`:

```
public class Entity1Configuration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Entity1>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Entity1> builder)
    {
        builder.ToContainer("Entity1");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.OwnsMany(x => x.Items, itemsBuilder =>
        {
            itemsBuilder.OwnsMany(t => t.SubItems, subitemsBuilder =>
            {
                subitemsBuilder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Finally, when I'm trying to access the elements of the `DbSet<Entity1> Entities1` I get an `InvalidOperationException` from EF Core:

```
        CosmosDbContext cosmosDbContext = new CosmosDbContext("https://localhost:8081", "myprivatekey", "Dev");
        cosmosDbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

        var entities = cosmosDbContext.Entities1.ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(entities.Count);
```

The Exception is this:

**System.InvalidOperationException**: 'When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and change it to not visit children of this type.'

The exception is throwed in the line:
`var entities = cosmosDbContext.Entities1.ToList();`

If I remove the `SubItems` property from the class `Item` everything works OK. I also tried change the provider of EF to OnMemory, and everything works perfect. I googled this exception with no luck so far. Can I have inner entities like my case with EF Core and CosmosDB provier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [Translation of Lambda in SqlTranslator throws exception](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/16597), it is a bug which has been fixed in newer EntityFrameworkCore package.

Please upgrade to latest version, for example: 3.1.0-preview2.19525.5. I tested at my side, and the problem was fixed.

Comment: I can't use preview packages in my environment 